# My Augmented Addition Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 3;
var b = 17;
var c = 12;

var a = a + 12;
var b = 9 + b + 2;
var c = c + 7:

/* Should Equal to 
a = 15
b = 26
c = 19
/*
```

My code can't run even though I tried can someone help me what my problem is?

Comment: There is a typo in line `var c = c + 7:`, there should be a semicolon, not a colon at the end. If this is not the only issue, what other errors do you get (BTW, it seems `b` should be `28`)?

Comment: Take a look at the developer console in your browser.  It's telling you about the syntax error on the last line.

Comment: You are adding 2 in your second calculation. 9 + 17 (b) + 2 will be 28, not 26. Why do you expect 26 exactly?

Comment: Please, consider to solve the typo and take a look if the error goes away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = 3;
var b = 17;
var c = 12;


a += 12;
b += 9;
c += 7;
```

Try that...

Comment: Ohh thanks that works, What is the function you used that is `+=` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 3;
var b = 17;
var c = 12;

a = a + 12;
b = 9 + b + 2;
c = c + 7;
```

Comment: There is still an error

Comment: @JohnGrabs: And *what* is the error?

Comment: @JohnGrabs This code alone isn't causing an error. If you're getting an error, we'd need to see the error to fix it, and it's being caused by other code.